# After resizing partition Ubuntu boots in emergency mode

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, mint

**After resizing /home directory** on my Ubuntu 18.04 (used Gparted while booting from LinuxMint-LiveCD **my Ubuntu boots exclusively in emergency mode**. What can I do to fix it?

I ran **lsblk** in emergency mode, and saw that:

1. my /dev/sda3 (/home) partition was unmounted (its size was changed)
2. unallocated space presumably still is considered as part of **sda** device (because **sda** size is shown as before 931Gb), but not recognized as /dev/sda4 or anyhow.

After mounting /dev/sda3 to the system I am able to start a normal session, but after reboot it happens again.

What can I do to make my Ubuntu boot normally again?

Content of */etc/fstab*:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=d5eb2396-e9df-4a63-84da-d628c915d809 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3E0D-5C34  /boot/efi       vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=f79558ec-8e55-4fa5-81ed-b6c77c87a43b /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: It will help if you add the contents of `/etc/fstab` and the output of the command `blkid` to your question

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Unfortunately you've added your blkid output twice and your fstab content not at all. Please copy and paste text rather than posting images of console output. Thank you for helping us help you

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What are the error messages from the failed boot? Also please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Re. *"P.S. I'm sorry for posting images instead of pasting text, I just find it yet confusing to deal with local markup rules. If I'd just pasted output here it would look unreadable, images do the job much better"*, Please read points 1-5 in [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals).

Comment: I'd upvote question if you fixed images of code, that really grinds my gears. Paste code from terminal.

Comment: _“I just find it yet confusing to deal with local markup rules.”_ Is it _so_ complicated to select the pasted code and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` icon? https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem in the following manner:

1. In the emergency mode, I ran `journalctl -xb | less` and searched for errors.

It appeared that `/dev/sda3` couldn't pass control sum check and therefore was refused to be mounted. Fortunately right there was a proposition to run manually `fsck /dev/sda3` to fix it.

2. I ran `fsck /dev/sda3` and, in a while, it fixed the problem.

Since then I didn't have problems booting into Ubuntu.

Comment: Less of a good idea, but another thing that may pass for a possible solution, in a similar case, is to change the value of `<pass>` parameter from 2 to 0 in `/etc/fstab` file for the corresponding partition. Then it won't be checked at all by `fsck` [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/fstab). Probably, maybe handy if certain properties of a partition change very often

Comment: While I understand what you would be doing if you changed the value of `<pass>` I would not encourage you to do this.  Failing the boot `fsck` indicates that there is a problem with the file system structure, and proceeding further could place the data stored on your disc in danger.